# cfhttp and Stripe APi

Tags: coldfusion, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get the stripe api working with 'cfhttp' but not having much luck.

```
<cfhttp
  url="https://api.stripe.com/Stripe/Stripe::setApiKey('MyLiveKeyHere');"
  authType="Basic" name="StripeAPI" method="Post">
> 
<cfoutput>#StripeAPI.statusCode#</cfoutput>
```

This gives me an error

> Message
>   Invalid CSV line size, expected 1 columns but found 2 instead
>   Detail
>   [message: You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY').

I cant find anything online that is helping me - anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The Stripe API key is not included in the URL like you are doing there, instead you pass it in an `Authorization` header : https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=curl#authentication That's why you get the error, but I don't know anything about ColdFusion or how you would set this up there.

Comment: You may want to check out https://github.com/jcberquist/stripe-cfml. That may help.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to do it - through trial and error...

```
  <cfhttp url="https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/*CustID*" method="Get">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer *Live Key Here*">
    </cfhttp>
```

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate with the Stripe API, you need to use either [basic auth or a bearer token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication) rather than placing the API key in the url. For example, to list charges you could do something like this:

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges" method="get" username="sk_test_xxxyyyz">
```

You'd then want to de-serialize the JSON response.