# Can I use CFHTTP to get Session information from Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, cfhttp

I am passing these tests back locally while I develop this the the return I get from Stripe, is there a quick way to parse this out with CFHTTP or something else, an example would be great I have done any coding in like 4 years and am sure rusty but I was asked to help a charity project out so I am doing my best.

http://localhost/Calendar%20Raffle%20Nashua%20Cal/checkoutcomplete.cfm?session_id=cs_test_a1aEXwN4d0PtyWxkHk9cgleupdYn6hlNgE3U4pMrmgr2UyEVhXkmvfQvbS

Comment: Ive tried something along these lines maybe im going in the right direction?

Comment: <cfhttp method = "GET" url="https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cs_test_a1aEXwN4d0PtyWxkHk9cgleupdYn6hlNgE3U4pMrmgr2UyEVhXkmvfQvbS" result = "content_1">

<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="sk_test_aHhoYVOnsayNSIleB1ETUCSq00vUOS9YVQ">

</cfhttp>

<CFSET content_1_data = DeserializeJSON(content_1.filecontent)>

<cfoutput>
#content_1_data.name#
</cfoutput>

Comment: I got it working but it dumps all data how do I get specific data i.e. that session id only?

Comment: <cfhttp method = "GET" url="https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions" result = "content_1">

<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer sk_test_aHhoYVOnsayNSIleB1ETUCSq00vUOS9YVQ">


</cfhttp>
<CFSET content_1 = DeserializeJSON(content_1.filecontent)>

<cfdump var="#content_1#">

Answer (score 0):

The same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779702/cfhttp-and-stripe-api) was asked before, and one of the answers suggests using a third-party library https://github.com/jcberquist/stripe-cfml. You might want to check it out and see if it helps.

Comment: Yeah this wasnt very useful, I have it working now however I get all the order not just the one I am asking for